# async-stream + anyhow is not Send

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a function that returns `Stream<Item=Result<..>>`.

```rs
use futures::StreamExt;
use parking_lot::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;

fn get_stream() -> impl futures::Stream<Item = anyhow::Result<u8>> {
    async_stream::try_stream! {
        let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(()));
        for item in &[1,2,3] {
            {
                let mut _guard = a.try_lock().expect("aa");
                Err(anyhow::anyhow!("asdf"))?;
            }
            {
                yield *item;
            }
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let _s = get_stream().boxed();
}
```

The mutex guard `_guard` should be immediately dropped, but `rustc` complains `get_stream` is not Send due to `_guard`.

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:22:27
   |
22 |     let _s = get_stream().boxed();
   |                           ^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
   = help: within `impl futures::Stream`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*mut ()`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
  --> src/main.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     async_stream::try_stream! {
7  | |         let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(()));
8  | |         for item in &[1,2,3] {
9  | |             {
...  |
16 | |         }
17 | |     }
   | |_____^ first, await occurs here, with `mut _guard` maybe used later...
note: `mut _guard` is later dropped here
  --> src/main.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     async_stream::try_stream! {
7  | |         let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(()));
8  | |         for item in &[1,2,3] {
9  | |             {
10 | |                 let mut _guard = a.try_lock().expect("aa");
   | |                     ---------- has type `parking_lot::lock_api::MutexGuard<'_, parking_lot::RawMutex, ()>` which is not `Send`
...  |
16 | |         }
17 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: this error originates in the macro `async_stream::try_stream` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Changing the order of statements to

```
Err(anyhow::anyhow!("asdf"))?;
let mut _guard = a.try_lock().expect("aa");
```

does not make compile error. Why is this? `anyhow` might generate a stacktrace, but does it capture local variables in `anyhow::Error`?

Comment: I think the problem is not in `anyhow`, but in the `?` operator in `try_stream!`. According to the docs, a fallible stream is simply a stream yielding `Result<T>`, with `yield` automatically inserting `Ok()`. This implies that `?` goes through the same await machinery as `yield` and a guard held at that point counts as being transferred across `.await`. If this analysis is correct, it should be reported to `async_stream` maintainers as a possible ergonomics issue - perhaps something can be done to fix it.

Comment: ^ Thanks, just found this from `cargo expand` and created the issue in async-stream.

Comment: In that case I suggest that you provide an answer, so that the question is marked resolved. It's a good question, after all. (Please include the link to the created issue as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the code expands to a match statement including an `.await` point where the `Err` is sent over the channel used to implement the stream:

```
let lock = a.try_lock();
match Err({
    let error = ::anyhow::private::format_err(
        match match () {
            () => [],
        } {
            ref args => unsafe { ::core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(&["asdf"], args) },
        },
    );
    error
}) {
    ::core::result::Result::Ok(v) => v,
    ::core::result::Result::Err(e) => {
        __yield_tx.send(::core::result::Result::Err(e.into())).await;
        return;
    }
};
// ..rest of the function
```

The lock is treated as alive for the entire `match` which includes the `await` point, thus you get an `!Send` future.

A more minimal example of this issue would be:

```
fn foo() -> impl Future<Output = ()> + Send {
    async {
        let e: Result<(), ()> = Err(());
        let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(()));
        let mut lock = a.lock();
        if e.is_err() {
            futures::future::ready(e).await;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The most straight-forward way to fix this is what you already do before `yield`ing the item at the end of the function: encapsulate all locking in a scope of its own without emitting any stream items within the scope.

This could be done through scoping within the function - becomes annoying when you want to emit errors using the `?` operator - or through sync functions or sync closures which lock the mutex internally and drop it before returning. This way you can get fairly ergonomic error handling through `?` on the results:

```
fn get_stream() -> impl futures::Stream<Item = anyhow::Result<u8>> {
    async_stream::try_stream! {
        let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(()));
        for item in &[1,2,3] {
            let scoped = || {
                let lock = a.try_lock().expect("aa");
                Err(anyhow::anyhow!("asdf"))?;
                Ok::<(), anyhow::Error>(*lock)
            };
            scoped()?;
            yield *item;
        }
    }
}
```